# Loop through * files using $1 in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am writing a script to act on files given to the script using the $1 variable. What is the best way to loop through these files. At the moment I have hard coded the script using something like

```
for file in *.pdf
do 
   act on $file
done
```

However I would rather do this using the $1 variable
Thanks
Barry

Comment: you can do `for file in $1` inside the code... to ensure, shell doesn't expand `*`, put that argument inside single quotes

Answer (score 4):

`$1` is simply the first parameter passed to your shell script.  So if you have a  script `myscript` and I call it like this:

```
myscript somefile
```

Then `$1` will be `somefile`.  If I call it like this:

```
myscript *
```

And there happen to be files in my current directory named:

```
foo bar baz
```

Then `$1` will be `foo`.  In either case, `$1` only has a single value and there is nothing to loop over.

There are a couple of ways to loop over the arguments.  The most common is:

```
for file in "$@"; do
  echo doing something with "$file"
done
```

Note that `$@` is not the same as `"$@"`; the latter is a special construct that will correctly deal with filenames that contain spaces.  You could also do something like:

```
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
  echo doing something with "$1"
  shift
done
```

Here, the `shift` command drops the first parameter, and `$2` becomes `$1` (and so on). This will loop as long as `$1` is non-empty.  You could also use `$#` for this (a variable which contains the number of command line arguments):

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    echo arg: "$1"
    shift
done
```

Comment: Note that the canonical (and most portable) way to write `for file in "$@"` is `for file do`.

Comment: I have honestly never seen that syntax used in practice.  Are you aware of any Bourne-ish shells that don't work properly given `for file in "$@"`?

Comment: It doesn't work properly in some versions of the Bourne shell when $# is 0. It doesn't work with the Bourne shell or pdksh when $IFS is empty (doesn't contain space for the Bourne shell).

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
script *.pdf
```

`*.pdf` is already expanded on the command line, and `$1` will only refer to the first file

```
for file in $1
```

will therefore not do what you need. You could use

```
for file in "$@"
```

instead.

See the section *Special Parameters* in the `man bash`

Comment: Arrgghhh!  Don't say `for file in $@`; that will fail if arguments contain spaces or various other special characters.  Use `for file in "$@"`, or just plain `for file` for short.